# "Parameter not valid" when adding PictureBox to TabControl

Tags: c#, image, visual-studio, winforms, bitmap

So I'm getting this error in my program. The below code shows where I dynamically add TabControl and PictureBoxes to a form on load. The images for the PictureBoxes are either a new set of screenshots that my program takes, or if the user has an unfinished ticket, it will load the previous screenshots into `activeticket.Screenshots` and use those instead. If the program takes new screenshots, the below code works perfectly. However, if the program tries to load previous screenshots, which are saved in a `.png` format and loaded in a `.bmp` format, I get the `"Parameter not valid"` exception  thrown and can't continue.

```
        //IF COUNT OF SCREENSHOTS IN ACTIVE TICKET IS ZERO
        //TAKE NEW SCREENSHOTS AND ASSIGN TO TABS 
        //ELSE ASSIGN EXISTING SCREENSHOTS TO TABS

        List<Bitmap> screenshots;

        if (activeticket.Screenshots.Count == 0)
        {
            screenshots = clsTools.TakeScreenshotList();
            foreach (Bitmap bmp in screenshots)
            {
                activeticket.Screenshots.Add(bmp);
            }
        }

        //REMOVE DEFAULT TAB
        tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(Tab1);

        foreach (Bitmap bmp in activeticket.Screenshots)
        {
            TabPage tp = new TabPage();
            PictureBox pb = new PictureBox()
            {
                Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
                SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage,
                Image = bmp
            };

            tp.Controls.Add(pb); //PARAMETER NOT VALID ON THIS LINE
            tabControl1.Controls.Add(tp);
            tp.Text = "Screen";
            CheckBox cb = new CheckBox()
            {
                Text = "Include in ticket",
                Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Right,
                AutoSize = true,
                Location = new Point(558, 345),
                Checked = true
            };
            tp.Controls.Add(cb);
            cb.BringToFront();
        }
```

Here is my code for loading the images. Please note that ImageFilenames is  string list containing the paths for the images.

```
       internal void LoadScreenCaptures()
       {
          foreach (string file in ImageFilenames)
          {
             var Screencaps = new Bitmap(file);
             Screenshots.Add(Screencaps);
             Screencaps.Dispose(); //DISPOSE IS HERE SO I CAN DELETE FILES BELOW
       }

        foreach (string file in ImageFilenames)
        {
            File.Delete(file);   
        }
    }
```

I've tried using an `ImageConverter`, I've tried about 15 different ways including `pb.Image = Image.FromFile(file)` and I'm having no luck! Here's the stack trace:

```
  at System.Drawing.Image.get_FrameDimensionsList()
   at System.Drawing.ImageAnimator.CanAnimate(Image image)
   at System.Drawing.ImageAnimator.ImageInfo..ctor(Image image)
   at System.Drawing.ImageAnimator.Animate(Image image, EventHandler onFrameChangedHandler)
   at System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox.Animate(Boolean animate)
   at System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox.Animate()
   at System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox.OnParentChanged(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.AssignParent(Control value)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection.Add(Control value)
   at System.Windows.Forms.TabPage.TabPageControlCollection.Add(Control value)
   at SETL.StartPage.StartPage_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\aaminahabdallah\Documents\Code\Ticketing\UI\Main UI\StartPage.cs:line 179
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `Screenshots.Add((Bitmap)Screencaps.Clone());`

Comment: Thank you friend, a little code editing on my part and this worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [@Jimi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7444103/jimi) answer, I added the line 
    Screenshots.Add((Bitmap)Screencaps.Clone());
in place of 
    Screenshots.Add(Screencaps);

I then did a bit of editing of the other parts of my code to fit around this, and it worked! Thank you!